# dealing with foreign characters in python

Tags: python, foreign-keys, special-characters

I am having a problem dealing with special characters like '€'.

TEXT contains prices in different currency's, and different formats

```
 TEXT example:
    $ 11.00 USD
    $ 9.58 USD
    559,89 pуб.
    $ 9.58
    8,10€
    7,05€
    8,10€
    CDN$ 11.00
    22,10 TL
    $ 9.58 USD
```

I am trying to sort the different prices in to different lists,

```
USD = []
RUS = []
EUR = []
TYR = []
CND = []
for link in TEXT:
    href = link.text.strip()
    if 'USD' in href:
        href = href.replace("$","")
        href = href.replace(" ","")
        href = href.replace("USD","")
        href = float(float(href))
        USD.append(href)
    elif 'pуб' in href:
        href = href.replace("pуб","")
        href = href.replace(" ","")
        href = href.replace(".",",")
        href = float(float(href))
        RUS.append(href)
    elif '€' in href:
        href = href.replace("€","")
        href = href.replace(" ","")
        href = href.replace(".",",")
        href = float(float(href))
        EUR.append(href)
    elif 'TL' in href:
        href = href.replace("TL","")
        href = href.replace(" ","")
        href = float(float(href))
        TYR.append(href)
    elif 'CND' in href:
        href = href.replace("CND$","")
        href = href.replace(" ","")
        href = float(float(href))
        CND.append(href)
    else:
        print("unknown currency")
```

but I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd1' in file C:/Users/S/PycharmProjects/untitled1/demo.py on line 26, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

because it docent recognize the symbols: pуб, € ...

Comment: Have you tried add # -*- coding: UTF-8 -*- at the beginning of your file?

Comment: Have you tried reading the URL **in the error output**?

Comment: __author__ = 'S'
# coding=utf-8 this is the header of my program, isn't it enough?

Answer (score 0):

Specify the source encoding:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```